# The kernel and the image of a group homomorphism intersect trivially

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

If $G$ is finite abelian group and $f: G \rightarrow G$ is a group homomorphism, how can I show that there exists an $n$ such that $\ker(f^n)$ intersects trivially with $f^n(G)$?

My thought:
Since $G$ is finite, then there is $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f^{n+1} = f^n$.

Then, I pick $g$ in $\ker(f^n) \cap f^n(G)$, then
$f^n(g)=e_G$ and $g=f^n(h)$ for some $h \in G$.

Since $f$ is a group homomorphism then so $f^n$, it follows that $f^n(e_G) =e_G$.

Can I say that $g = e_G$?

It seems that $\ker(f^n)$ is always the trivial subgroup of $G$.

Comment: It's not clear to me what $n$ is supposed to be. It is certainly not true that the kernel of $f$ always intersects trivially with the image of $f$. Are you trying to show that there exists $n$ such that the kernel of $f^n$ intersects trivially with the image of $f^n$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, yes. For the existence of $n$, since $f:G \rightarrow G$ is a group homomorphism then so is $f^k$ for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and since $G$ is finite, then the sequence $\{f^k \}_{k}$ must stabilize, i.e. there should be some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f^{n+1} = f^n$. Right?

Comment: It should be $\exists m,\exists d>0:\ f^{m}=f^{m+d}$

Comment: @NDB, then can we say they intersect trivially?

Comment: I have edited  the question to make it match what you say in the comments.

Comment: @ancientmathematician thank you!

Comment: It is false that there must exist $n$ such that $f^n=f^{n+1}$. Consider a group like $C_m\times C_m$ and the map $f(a,b)=(b,a)$. It is *never* true that $f^n=f^{n+1}$. As NDB says, you *can* say that the sequence $\{f^n\}$ eventually *repeats*, but it is not necessarily  true that it eventually stabilizes.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, that's correct! Then can I find an $n$ such that $ker(f^n) \cap f^n(G) =\{e_G \}?

Comment: $\ker(f)\leq \ker(f^2)\leq \cdots \leq \ker(f^k)\leq\cdots$. Show that if $\ker(f^k)=\ker(f^{k+1})$ then $\ker(f^k)=\ker(f^{k+r})$ for all $r\geq 0$. If $g\in \ker(f^{k})\cap\mathrm{Im}(f^k)$ then $g=f^k(h)$, so $e=f^k(g) = f^{2k}(h)$, so $h\in \ker(f^{2k})=\ker(f^k)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, and if $g,h \in ker(f^{k})$, then $g=h=e$, right?

Comment: No. The point is that $h\in\ker(f^k)$, and $g=f^k(h)$. You never conclude (nor can you conclude) that $g=h$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, Oh, I thought this leads to the show that $g=e$. Then, how can we show that $ker(f^n) \cap f^n(G) = \{e\}$?

Comment: Yes, it leads to show that $g=e$. It does *not* lead to show that $g=h$. Because *that* is not necessarily true, and I don't know why you insist on trying to get $g=h$.